# Trying to upgrade from postgresql-9.4 to 9.5 after upgrading Fedora 21 to 25

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have recently updated Fedora 21 to 25. I thought I had caught most issues and decided it was time to update Rails and postgresql but I am stuck on the latter.

Postgresql was functioning without visible issues prior to updating to Fedora 25. I can access my database through my Rails application and have CRUD functions so I believe the database is still good.

But, if I try to open postgresql CLI using `psql database_name` I can not access the database and receive the following error message:

```
psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsslInUse
```

I get the same error for anything calling `psql`, i.e. `psql --version` gives the same error.

The command `postgresql-setup upgrade` tells me I am "using obsoleted argument syntax" and states `arguments transformed to: postgresql-setup --upgrade --unit postgresql`. This generates the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot upgrade because the database in /var/lib/pgsql/data is of
version 9.3 but it should be 9.4
```

When I look at the above directory it appears that I have 2 data directories, the one noted above that holds a file `PG_VERSION` that stores `9.3` and there is also `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data` that holds a file `PG_VERSION` that stores `9.4`.

So, how do I find out which database version has my current database? If I have been operating on postgresql 9.3 how do I move to 9.4 and then to 9.5 (eventually to 9.6!).

Comment: find which `psql` you use. one of `whereis psql`, `locate psql` or `sudo find / -name psql` will give you the list that you have installed.

Comment: OK, tried all those commands, `which psql` gives `/usr/bin/psql`, `whereis` gives ``psql: /usr/bin/psql /usr/share/man/man1/psql.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/psql.1`, `locate psql` gives a list of locations, the majority of which start with `/usr/pgsql-9.4/`. There are no references to 9.3 in the lists. 

I'm going to try deleting (by renaming) the `data` directory that I don't think I need and see what happens.

Comment: So now when I try to run `postgresql-setup upgrade`  there are new errors, relating to deleting that `data` directory. These are `ERROR: config file /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf is not readable or does not exist
FATAL: Old cluster in '/var/lib/pgsql/data' does not seem to be initialized`. I guess I have to point postgres to `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data` somehow. I will do a little work on that and see where I get to.

Comment: `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data start`?..